# How to solve AttributeError: 'Client' object has no attribute 'apply_auth'?

Tags: python, tweepy

I'm having trouble with new and old documentation of tweepy, it seems that everything that worked in previous versions, but there are a lot of changes, I have a problem making it work right now. Any ideas why I have this error?

```
import tweepy

client = tweepy.Client(bearer_token='[redacted]', 
                       consumer_key='[redacted]', 
                       consumer_secret='[redacted]', 
                       access_token='[redacted]', 
                       access_token_secret='[redacted]')


api = tweepy.API(client)
public_tweets = api.home_timeline()
for tweet in public_tweets:
    print(tweet.text)
```

I get this error

```
AttributeError: 'Client' object has no attribute 'apply_auth'
```

Comment: BEWARE: Editing your question to remove your API credentials doesn't make them unavailable.  Older versions of your question are still available and still contain that information.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**First of all, you should IMMEDIATELY refresh all your personnal and applications tokens.**

Anyone can access the Twitter API on your behalf, it's like sharing your password publicly.

About your question: the `tweepy.Client` is used to access the version 2 of the Twitter API, while the `tweepy.API` is used to access the version 1.1 of the Twitter api.

So you can use them side by side, but they can not be mixed that way.

A quick fix could be:

```
auth = tweepy.OAuth1UserHandler(
    consumer_key, consumer_secret, access_token, access_token_secret
)

api = tweepy.API(auth)

public_tweets = api.home_timeline()

for tweet in public_tweets:
    print(tweet.text)
```